# What counts as cross-sectional units (within which observationsare embedded)?

Tags: econometrics, multiple-imputation, cross-section

Observations can be nested/embedded within cross-sections or cross-sectional units that are measured. For instance, populations are distributed across regions. There are various methods for dealing with that.

But how are cross-sectional units defined?

- Are they fixed?
- Must all observations be nested within them?  (or might some observations take missing values on the unit variable)
- May the spatial units 'move'?
- Do they differ from groups? How exactly?

Please consider the case of passengers aboard airplanes?flights. Groups of passengers are embedded in airplanes that move around. Variables such as longitude, latitude, and altitude vary at the level of the flights (or passenger groups). May flights be considered a cross-sectional unit?

I ask in the context of [multiple imputation using Amelia](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/Amelia.pdf).